# smtp;550 Access denied - Invalid HELO name (See RFC2821 4.1.1.1)

Tags: iis, smtp, iis-7.5

I'm running Windows server 2008 R2 but am getting smtp mail rejected from a few domains.

To test it I'm dropping a text file into C:\inetpub\mailroot\Pickup directory, with something like this:

```
From: my@emailaddress.com
To: someone@somewhere.com
Subject: testing

This is a test
```

It will send to some domains, but some are returning:

```
Reporting-MTA: dns;DEDICAT-93I3U5A
Received-From-MTA: dns;DEDICAT-93I3U5A
Arrival-Date: Wed, 8 Aug 2012 12:50:58 +0100

Final-Recipient: rfc822;someone@somewhere.com
Action: failed
Status: 5.5.0
Diagnostic-Code: smtp;550 Access denied - Invalid HELO name (See RFC2821 4.1.1.1)
```

I understand this could be something to do with the smtp setup on the server (IIS 7.5).
Can anybody give me some advice as to where to start please?

Thanks,

Andy.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Some SMTP servers require you to send a valid host name with the HELO command that also is the same as the reverse DNS of the IP address the request originates from.

You can configure the host name the IIS SMTP Server uses through the old IIS6 Management Console. To do so, select the SMTP Server, right click and select `Properties`, go to the tab `Delivery` and then click on the button `Advanced`.

The reverse DNS for your IP address is usually controlled by your ISP.

Comment: It might suffice to change the local host identifier (apparently `DEDICAT-93I3U5A`?) to a FQDN.

Comment: Note that the [SMTP protocol](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5321#section-4.1.4) says: "An SMTP server MAY verify that the domain name argument in the EHLO command actually corresponds to the IP address of the client. However, if the verification fails, **the server MUST NOT refuse to accept a message on that basis**."

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, I had the same problem using hMailServer, and found the configuration instructions [here](http://www.hmailserver.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=18710).  For the benefit of other hMailServer users, here's the field you need to set:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please try enabling SMTP authentication with TLS

```
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.required=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the solution to the problem.

Set the `Authorization property` before creating session as below.

```
properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
```

Comment: -1 What language is this?  And who even says he's doing this in code?