# com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 550 Access denied

Tags: email, coldfusion, smtp

I am trying since yesterday but no luck. I am getting this weird error message which doesn't have much information or solution on the Internet.

> A problem occurred when attempting to deliver mail.
>
> This exception was caused by:
>   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 550 Access denied - Invalid
>   HELO name (See RFC2821 4.1.1.1) ; nested exception is:
>   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSenderFailedException: 550 Access denied -
>   Invalid HELO name (See RFC2821 4.1.1.1) .

Code that sends email via SMTP

```
<cfmail 
    from="no-reply@example.com"
    server="mail.example.com"
    to="example@gmail.com"
    username="no-reply@example.com" 
    password="password"
    port=587
    subject="ColdFusion Email">ColdFusion</cfmail>
```

I use the same server, username and password on our PHP websites using PHPMailer everything works fine only on ColdFusion websites am getting this error.

Please advise

Comment: Do you use `from="no-reply@example.com"` in your code or is this just a sample?

Comment: @BernhardDöbler ofcause sample

Comment: A brief google suggests it may be caused by the host name sent in the EHLO/HELO. See [4.1.1.1  Extended HELLO (EHLO) or HELLO (HELO)](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2821#section-4.1.1.1) and [smtp;550 Access denied - Invalid HELO name (See RFC2821 4.1.1.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11864227/smtp550-access-denied-invalid-helo-name-see-rfc2821-4-1-1-1)