# Invalid HELO name on sending with TIDSmtp

Tags: delphi, indy, indy10

When using Delphi 2007 and Indy 10.6.2.0, I'm having the error below when trying to use `TIdSMTP` in a specific account:

> Access denied - Invalid HELO name (See RFC2821 4.1.1.1)

It's the first time I have seen this error. Other accounts send without problems. Due to security reasons, I cannot provide the credentials, but the account is on port 587 and using SSL with the options below:

```pascal
SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1;
SSLOptions.VerifyMode := [];
SSLOptions.VerifyDepth := 0;
OnStatusInfo := ssl1statusinfo;
```

Comment: Did you assign a name to `TIdSMTP.HeloName`? Some servers require this.

Comment: @whosrdaddy Nope, what should i assign ?

Comment: never mind, probably the smtp server needs authentication. Did you verify & test with an email client (like Mozilla thunderburd) that you actually can send emails?

Comment: [maybe related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11926211/800214)

Comment: did you tried other libs? personally i ended doing SMTP with Ararat Synapse library. It is simplistic and perhaps even barebone, but because if that i could debug into its code and see how it works internally and so forth. Eveyr time i looked at Indy it felt like huge overengineering for me, like a maze that i maybe won't find exit from :-)

Comment: @Arioch'The Thanks for the suggestion but so far Indy has worked really well for me, and they have a good support too. At this moment change library would be a hassle

Comment: @whosrdaddy Yes, on Thunderbird same credentials work !

Comment: Then use something like Microsoft Network Monitor or WireShark to intercept and parse SMTP traffic. See which HELO and other commands were sent by Thunderbird and by your app and think about differences. You may need to temporarily turn off SSL, or perhaps there are TLS MITM modules for those utilities, dunno

Answer (score 1):

As @whosrdaddy stated in comments, `TIdSMTP.HeloName` is the solution to your error. This is not an authentication or SSL issue. Set the `HeloName` to an appropriate DNS hostname representing your client, for instance from [`GetComputerNameEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getcomputernameexa), or at least your public IP address. If you don't set a `HeloName`, `TIdSMTP` uses the local machine's hostname or computer name, which may or may not be in the proper DNS format for the SMTP server to accept, depending on configuration. Some servers don't care about this, but some do.

Comment: Thanks but i try setting TIDSmtp.HeloName using my hostname, local ip and public ip, but none worked, the same error remains :X

Comment: Maybe i can send you the credentials, so you can debug why is not sending ?

Comment: @delphirules no, because the error happens before authentication occurs, during the initial SMTP handshake when client and server are greeting each other, so the credentials are irrelevant. And my hostname would be different than yours. You are likely going to have to contact the server admin and ask why your client is being denied access. Maybe the server uses a whitelist of allowed machines and your machine is not on the list.

Comment: This is unlikely, because simply using Thunderbird without any special settings, it will work... I found this topic : https://www.techieshelp.com/the-server-responded-550-access-denied-microsoft-outlook/ , maybe is something related ?

Comment: I contacted the email provider, they said there is no special requirement for the HELO... it seems something is missing on TIdSmtp

Comment: I assure you, there isn't anything missing. The provider will likely need to analyze your SMTP session on their end to find out where the failure is actually coming from. You are getting an error message from the server, so they need to figure out why it is failing. Did you do what Arioch suggested and capture the network traffic from Thunderbird and compare it to the network traffic from TIdSMTP to see if there are any differences?

Comment: Today i had this problem again and actually, the problem did not has anything to do with helo name... It was an incorrect password but somehow, instead of telling the password was wrong, the server returned this invalid helo name... who knows